# SharePoint 2013 Search Results in raw XML

Tags: 2013, search-results, xml

I'm setting up some Search Query Webparts but we have a LOT of managed properties (1,200+).

So it would have been great to be able to see a search result in raw XML in order to know, which properties are found.

I can see online that it is possible in SP2010 by excluding xsl, but can I do sometging similar in SP 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a couple ways. If you REALLY want to use a Display Template you can create a copy of the Default Item Template and then replace the body div with:

```
<div id=”Item_PropertyList”>
 <!-–#_
if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem)){
 for (var key in ctx.CurrentItem)
 {
 var value = ctx.CurrentItem[key];
 console.log(“Value: ” + value);
 _#–->
 <div> _#= $htmlEncode(key) =#_ : _#= $htmlEncode(value) =#_ </div>
 <!–-#_
 }
 }
 _#–->
 <hr>
 </div>
```

If you haven't done this before use this post as a guide: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2014/03/01/create-a-diagnostic-display-template/

Alternatively you can use the **awesome** SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool to return RAW results for your viewing pleasure. http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 search result web part uses display templates.

You can go to Search Service Application in central admin. Then open "Search Schema" to find all Managed Properties.

If you want to test out, then click on Result Sources. Then "New Result Source", from the dialog use "Launch Query Builder".